# Undefined constant error when using namespace in Symfony

Tags: php, namespaces, constants

PHP 5.6
Symfony 3

I have a file in a bundle that contains a namespace with defined constants...

constfile.php

```
<?php
namespace Some\Interesting\ConstFile {
    const NAME_OF_CONSTANT = 'Some Constant';
}
namespace Some\Interesting\ConstFile\Specific {
    const NAME_OF_SPECIFIC_CONSTANT = 'Some Specific Constant';
}
```

Then I have another file in another bundle which I'm trying to use the constants...

stuff.php

```
<?php
namespace More\Cool\Stuff;

use Some\Interesting\ConstFile as CF;
use Some\Interesting\ConstFile\Specific as CFS;

class Stuff {
    public function doit() {    
        $output->writeln(CF\NAME_OF_CONSTANT);
        $output->writeln(CFS\NAME_OF_SPECIFIC_CONSTANT);
    }
}
```

PHPStorm doesn't have any complaints with this set up. However, when I run this, I'm getting a 'Fatal error: Undefined constant NAME_OF_CONSTANT in stuff.php' error.

Answer (score 3):

This error could also happen when you mistake and prefix your namespace with an anti slash. 
***Use*** statements can be prefixed by ***\***, ***namespace*** can not. 
A leading anti slash in namespace is causing php to understand the whole line as constant.

Answer (score 2):

The auto-load does not work well when try to load this type of files, try including the original file manually.

```
require 'path/to/constfile.php'
```